# Why is css float behaving different with <ul> and <li>?

Tags: css-float, css

Taken from [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_float5) (visit link to see what it looks like):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      ul
      {
        float:left;
        width:100%;
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
        list-style-type:none;
      }
      a
      {
        float:left;
        width:6em;
        text-decoration:none;
        color:white;
        background-color:purple;
        padding:0.2em 0.6em;
        border-right:1px solid white;
      }
      a:hover {background-color:#ff3300;}
      li {display:inline;}
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Link one</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link two</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link three</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link four</a></li>
    </ul>

    <p>
    In the example above, we let the ul element and the a element float to the left.
    The li elements will be displayed as inline elements (no line break before or after the element). This forces the list to be on one line.
    The ul element has a width of 100% and each hyperlink in the list has a width of 6em (6 times the size of the current font).
    We add some colors and borders to make it more fancy.
    </p>

  </body>
</html>
```

So, `ul` and `a` are `float:left;`. Now, float says that the next element should float around it, yet the text *does not*. What am I missing?

Second: Removing the `float` from the `ul` **makes the text flow around it**. What the serious heck?

Third: Removing the `inline` from `li` **does nothing**. Yet, removing the `float` from `a` **puts whitespace between the elements**.

Can *anyone* even try to explain why these things happen and don’t do what they should?

(Newest Chromium)

Comment: Please, read the question first. Stupid speed contest on SO.

Comment: @AlienWebguy Thanks for that link. I didn’t know that (I’ve noticed some interesting examples on w3schools, though). I should inform myself next time before I use a web service for learning something so crucial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The width of the `<ul>` is `100%`. The text has nowhere to go but below it.

The reason removing `float:left` from the `<ul>` will make the text appear to the right is that the `<ul>` will not be taking up visual space anymore since the contents are all floated inside a non-floated container. It will be 0px tall, and the `<p>` will STILL drop down below it because of the 100% width, but you won't notice it visually. You can test this by giving the `<ul>` a border and see what happens. The `<p>` will float next to the last floated `<li>`.

`<li>`s are not inline items. `display:inline;` and `display:block` are both incorrect. They are `display:list-item;`

Comment: Nothing dangerous about HTML & CSS :)

Answer (score 1):

It’s because when you set the `<ul>` width to 100%, the `<ul>` takes up the full width & pushes content below it. Changing your `<ul>` width to `auto` will achieve the effect you want:

```
  ul
  {
    float:left;
    width:auto;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    list-style-type:none;
  }
```